# Hover not working with nth-child

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors

He I am exploring the features of CSS 3 and I walked into some trouble:

For a table I have made this CSS:

```
table.sortable tbody tr td {
    border-bottom:1px solid;
    height: 20px;
}

table.sortable tbody tr:hover {
    background-color:#BCD2E5 !important;
}

table.sortable tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: #F3FAFF;
}
table.sortable tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

table.new{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 187);
}

table.reaction{
    background-color: rgb(255, 128, 64);
}

table.send{
    background-color: rgba(154, 211, 109, 0.470588);
}
```

The problem is that the hover is not working but if I comment the nth-child selector out it does actually work. Also in some cases I have to give some rows different background color's. This is for the users so they can see the status of some stuf really easy. So if I assign a class like `class="send"` to a row it has to get the background color form the class send.

Why is this not working out?! or did I miss something!?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle where you could replicate this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are applying the `background-color` for the `nth-child` rows to the `td`. The `background-color` on the `td` is showing above the `background-color` of the `tr`.

Changing your CSS to the following worked for me (remove the `td` from the end `nth-child` selectors):

```
table.sortable tbody tr:hover {
    background-color:#BCD2E5 !important;
}

table.sortable tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #F3FAFF;
}
table.sortable tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

---

**OR**

Add `td` to the end of your `hover` selector, like so:

```
table.sortable tbody tr:hover td {
    background-color:#BCD2E5 !important;
}
```

See this codepen: http://codepen.io/keithwyland/pen/woLmh

---

**ALSO**

If you move the `hover` selector *after* the `nth-child` selectors in the CSS, then you shouldn't need the `!important`. So, like this:

```
table.sortable tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #F3FAFF;
}
table.sortable tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

table.sortable tbody tr:hover {
    background-color:#BCD2E5;
}
```

Comment: Ah of course I feel so stupid now, that I din't saw that that is brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Try not to feel stupid though! Practice is how we all learn. Keep it up!

Comment: I just figured out that because the browser cash the modified CSS was not downloaded. But still I have not seen the td till you pointed towards it.